# COM/ActiveX DLL to consume WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, com, wcf-client

I am trying to extend an application which supports COM/ActiveX objects. The COM dll needs to send some data to other system on local network for further processing and actions.

I have tested a basic WCF Host-Client setup and it works fine from console client to console host. But now I need to send data through a client in com-visible dll.

This is the code of the dll :

```
namespace Client
{
[Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ISend
{
    [DispId(1)]
    bool SendData(string msg);
}
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"), ProgId("Client.Send")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Send : ISend
{
    static BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    static EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://192.168.1.6:8000/WCFHost/Service/GetData"));

    GetDataClient client = new GetDataClient(binding, endpoint);
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public bool SendData(string msg)
    {       
        try
        {
            if (client.getData(msg))
            {
                client.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                client.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            client.Abort();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The dll works fine as a reference but cannot create object through target application(It has the functionality to access COM/ActiveX objects). When I try to access the dll by :

```
obj = CreateObject ("Client.Send");
obj.SendData("Hello")
```

It says :

`COM/object handle is null`

on second line nothing more!

I created a com-visible dll in similar way using Remoting to achieve this and it worked like a charm. But now its not working as a WCF Client.

It would be really appreciated if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

I had moved to Remoting where this was not a problem, but I was suggested to stay away from it and achieve this through WCF.

P.S : I am new to C# so please excuse any stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

COM does not support static methods, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182198.aspx) for further details. You'll need to remove the `static` keyword from the class in order to let your client create an instance. This will also allow you to implement the interface, which is not possible for static classes.

As a side note, your code shouldn't even compile, since the `static` modifier on an interface is illegal. Remove it as well, then recompile and re-register your DLL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Actual code doesn't have the static modifier. I made the mistake while posting the question. I have updated the changes.